# Customized width in percent to specific grid-area inside a css grid container with 12 areas, 7 rows and 4 columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html5-canvas, css-grid

**Note: not a duplicated because this is a custom made solution and no other answer answers this cuestion. This is also a solution with pure CSS, without Jquery, neither Bootstrap.**

I am changing my website layout from CSS-tablets to CSS-grid, the grid layout contains 12 grid-template-areas, 7 grid-template-rows and 4 grid-template-columns.

Because of the 4 columns, the default width is set to 1fr or 25% and that is ok, but I need 1 grid-template-rows (the fifth row) to have a customized width and it is not working, with the following custom width:

```
main main main 60% together in total
aside 40% in total
```

Here is the CSS I have until now

```
body, html {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;
box-sizing:border-box;text-align:center;
width:100%;height:100%}
body {font-size:16px;font-weight:400;color:#121212}

.container {display:grid; 
grid-template-rows:auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
grid-template-columns:25% 25% 25% 25%;
grid-template-areas: 
    'language language date date'
    'logo logo logo logo'
    'mobile mobile mobile mobile'
    'nav nav nav nav'
    'main main main aside' 
    'alerts weather categories about'
    'footer footer footer footer';
gap:0px;height:100%;}
  
#language {background-color:#a7e779;grid-area:language;}
#date {background-color:#badb68;grid-area:date;}
#logo {background-color:#8fbccb;grid-area:logo;}
#mobile {background-color:#dae799;grid-area:mobile;}
#nav {background-color:#b7b78e;grid-area:nav;}

#main {background-color:#dfe575;grid-area:main;width:60%}
#aside {background-color:red;grid-area:aside;width:40%}

#alerts {background-color:#baedcd;grid-area:alerts;}
#weather {background-color:#cb7ba7;grid-area:weather;}
#categories {background-color:#6998e5;grid-area:categories;}
#about {background-color:#cc79de;grid-area:about;}
#footer {background-color:#7d88d9;grid-area:footer;}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="language">language</div>
  <div id="date">date</div>
  <div id="logo">logo</div>
  <div id="mobile">mobile</div>
  <div id="nav">nav</div>
  <div id="main">main must be 60%</div>
  <div id="aside">aside must be 40%</div>
  <div id="alerts">alerts</div>
  <div id="weather">weather</div>
  <div id="categories">categories</div>
  <div id="about">about</div>
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

I also created a Codepen to see it in action here
https://codepen.io/familias/pen/gOQWgeM

As you can see in the demo or code, the layout is not respecting the 60% and 40% values and is just displaying it smaller instead.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't do that. Columns are always the width you set them and in this case you set 25%. You can't then set row column to 60%.

Comment: I'd suggest you use more columns and adjust widths accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Any sugestion?

Comment: Very good idea, I will try with 10 columns that way will be easier to set %

Comment: I'd have to think but 20 columns seems to jump out as being able to cope with the various multiples you need.

Comment: Yes I was trying now with 10 and it was not going goo. I also think 20 is the perfect solution

Comment: Solved!!! Thank you very much Paulie

Answer (score 1):

The solution (all credits to Paulie_D)

The is no way to fix it in the way I was trying, so the only way to achieve it is by creating more columns, in my case I created 20 columns and every one of them would mean 5% width so I just make MAIN to be 60% width by using  12 columns (5% each) and the aside 40% by using 8 columns (5% each)

The code is the following

HTML

```
<div class="angry-grid">
  <div id="item-0">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-1">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-2">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-3">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-4">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-5">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-6">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-7">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-8">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-9">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-10">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="item-11">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.angry-grid {
   display: grid; 

   grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   
   grid-template-areas: 
    'language language language language language language language language language language date date date date date date date date date date'
    'logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo logo'
    'mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile mobile'
    'nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav'
    'main main main main main main main main main main main main aside aside aside aside aside aside aside aside'
    'alerts alerts alerts alerts alerts weather weather weather weather weather categories categories categories categories categories about about about about about'
    'footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer';
   
   gap: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   
}
  
#item-0 {

   background-color: #a65598; 
   grid-area: language;
   
}
#item-1 {

   background-color: #db979d; 
   grid-area: date;
   
}
#item-2 {

   background-color: #7eeb8f; 
   grid-area: logo;
   
}
#item-3 {

   background-color: #7ab5eb; 
   grid-area: mobile;
   
}
#item-4 {

   background-color: #d797ac; 
   grid-area: nav;
   
}
#item-5 {

   background-color: #669d99; 
   grid-area: main;
   
}
#item-6 {

   background-color: #5ba9f6; 
   grid-area: aside;
   
}
#item-7 {

   background-color: #966ed9; 
   grid-area: alerts;
   
}
#item-8 {

   background-color: #7b76d5; 
   grid-area: weather;
   
}
#item-9 {

   background-color: #76c575; 
   grid-area: categories;
   
}
#item-10 {

   background-color: #d6c7af; 
   grid-area: about;
   
}
#item-11 {

   background-color: #b5df6d; 
   grid-area: footer;
   
}
```

And to see it working on Codepen

https://codepen.io/familias/pen/gOQWgeM

I am sure a lot of new users want to learn. understand and solve this kind of problem with column widths. Here is the solution